# Can you disable warnings in Spyder 4.0?

Tags: python, spyder

I know you can disable both warnings and error flags from `Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > disable basic linting` but is it possible to disable only the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, that's not possible.